# Norm of an integral of a continuous function

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $f \in C[0,1]$, $f(1) = 0$.

Show that $\phi$ is bounded with norm $||\phi||_{\infty} = 1$.

$$\phi(f) = \int_0^1 f(x) dx$$

My guess was:

$||\phi||_{\infty} = || \int_0^1 f(x) dx ||_{\infty} = \int_0^1 ||f(x)||_{\infty}dx = \int_0^1 1 dx = 1 $

But I am not sure if I can do this?

Comment: What do $\|f(x)\|_\infty$ and $\left\|\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right\|_\infty$ *mean*?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The supremum norm

Comment: Second equality is wrong.

Comment: @geetha290krm Okay - why?

Comment: My question was what does it *mean*, not what is it called. Suppose that, say, $\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx=-3$. Then $\left\|\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right\|_\infty=\|-3\|_\infty$. What does $\|-3\|_\infty$ mean?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $f \in C[0,1]$ - how can it be $ < 0$?

Comment: @binaryBigInt the function $f(x)=x-1$ is continuous, $f(1)=0$ and is negative on the unit interval $[0,1]$

Comment: If $f(x)=-3$, then $\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx=-3$. What's the problem?

Comment: @binaryBigInt, what Jose is trying to tell you is that $\phi$ is an operator (a functional in fact) while $f$ is a function. So the symbol $\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty$ must have different meanings in each context.

Answer (score 0):

The norm $\| \phi \|_{\infty}$ here almost certainly refers to the *[operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm)*. Wikipedia lists lots of definitions that are all clearly equivalent. I'll use this one: $$\| \phi \|_\infty = \sup \{|\phi(f)| : f \in C[0,1], f(1) = 0, \|f\|_\infty \le 1\}.$$

Now, let $f$ be some function satisfying those three conditions. To solve the problem we need to show $|\phi(f)| \le 1$, and in fact we can compute:
$$\begin{align}
&-1 \le f(x) \le 1 \text{ for all } x \in [0,1] \\
\implies & -1 \le \int_0^1 f(x)dx \le 1 \\
\implies & -1 \le \phi(f) \le 1 \\
\implies & \quad|\phi(f)| \le 1.
\end{align}$$